# What Do You Do When There Is An Unexpected '{' But It Looks Like There Is Nothing Wrong?

Tags: php

There is an unexpected '{' but it looks like there is nothing wrong?

I have removed the curly bracket completely and the echo but did nothing when I put it back in.[This is the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9aXd.png)

I am not sure what the output is sorry?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Show us the whole code.

Comment: Code share we not god 

Comment: It’s not that the curly brace is wrong; it’s just not expecting it there/yet.  Look before the brace to find the problem. Hint: it’s what’s missing just before the brace. And, BTW, do check out the link above. It’s amazingly prescient.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parentheses at the end of line 2. Make sure that every opening parentheses has a corresponding closing parentheses. In the case of an if statement the round parens should end before you place any curly parens.

```
if(condition && (otherCondition)){
 code to execute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parenthesis after the isset - which is throwing your error. Simple fix:

```
if(condition && isset($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"])){
    . . .
}
```

Also, in the future, please paste your code in the original post as a code block - not an image. It helps other users debug your code.